# Multiple inheriting class names versus single and selective include

Tags: php

At the moment I essentially have:

```
A.php:         class A { ... }
A1.php:        class A1 extends A { A1 stuff... }
A2.php:        class A2 extends A { A2 stuff... }
...
factory.php:   create($obj) {return new $obj;}
```

I'm thinking of changing it to:

```
A.php:         class A { ... }
A1.php:        class B extends A { A1 stuff... }
A2.php:        class B extends A { A2 stuff... }
...
factory.php:   create($obj) { require ($obj.".php"); return new B; }
```

Any comments, or dangers that lie ahead? Only one class will ever get instantiated per PHP session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first impressions:

- You can never load both classes into memory at once. Even if you don't *usually* do this, it'll make, for example, unit testing hard.
- Debugging is made harder if your debugger tells you there's a problem with class `B`, but not *which* class `B`.
- A class describes a logical unit. There shouldn't be two logical units with the same name but different functionality.

Comment: Thanks for you thoughts. They've helped me decided against it.